# .NET Prism4 WVVM + WPF Asynchronous Calls Best Practices

Tags: .net, prism-4

I am currently getting started with the .NET Prism framework to develop a WPF application. One thing that I'm unable to determine is the best way to achieve asynchronous calls to a WCF service, or a database? The reason is, I don't want a WCF/DB call to block the UI thread, which causes the UI to just freeze until the operation is done.

From my understanding, I should be following the architecture:

```
View (WPF) <=> View Model <=> Application Services <=> DB/WCF
```

Do I implement the asynchronous behaviour in the view model using something like the [AsyncDelegateCommand](http://www.amazedsaint.com/2010/10/asynchronous-delegate-command-for-your.html)? If I do this, then I am unable to maintain any state in the application services, since setting any state needs to be done in the UI thread (unless there's a way around this).

So the other option is to provide async methods with callbacks in the application services and have the application services spawn threads/tasks for the asynchronous operations.

I briefly looked into the Prism StockTrader reference implementation, and they don't seem to do anything asynchronously. I feel that this should be a very common problem, and there must be some best practices out there to deal with this.

Comment: Oh, and one other thing... you don't really need an "AsyncDelegateCommand".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't found anything online in terms of a "Best Practice".

Personally I think the following setup is good: `View <= BINDING => ViewModel <==> DataRepository/DataAccessLayer (Async Calls)`

As far as keeping your ViewModel in sync with the DAL you can do a couple of things depending on what data is needed to be synced:

- Expose `ReadOnlyObservableCollection<T>`s for collections of your models and manage their backing collections internally (from within the DAL).
- For single items return a new instance of the item and load the item on the async completed event.
- Also, learn to love the EventAggregator (it's not overly complex -- Though, there are improvements to it online -- [EventAggregator Extension](http://codepaste.net/woqq1d)). It helps a lot. It's better to use this to announce "working" and "completed" events.

Basically, since the Service Reference Generator helps build Async calls for you, just work with that and use your DataRepository/DAL to manage the data internally exposing references to your ViewModels and the EventAggregator to announce Working/Completed.

---

I should also say this... you can choose to make your DAL completely synchronous and have all async calls to/from it on the ViewModel since you'll probably want to expose some type of "IsWorking/Completed" properties to let the view know something is happening or it's done. I think the key is to ensure that you stick all asynchronousity on one layer (not the View though). Doing it on the ViewModel layer makes it more coding work building the async calls, but it's a lot cleaner. You're DAL only does things synchronously and does not have to publish completed/isworking events. In fact, I'd actually say this is the more common approach.

Comment: So essentially, the ViewModel should make the call and listen to the completed event. The async should be done under the ViewModel. The EventAggregator is an interesting idea. However, my problem with this is that, most of the time, I want only the caller to get the results of the async request. In this case, I think sending down a callback from the ViewModel would be appropriate.

Comment: Well, I don't like to have my DAL tightly coupled with my ViewModels, so I don't want to tie the completed event to my ViewModel. Instead, the CompletedEvent is handled internally on the DAL so I won't ever get into the hot mess of adding/removing event handlers (no worry about memory leaks). If I need to communicate completed/working from the DAL to "whoever is listening" (ViewModel) I use the EventAggregator. Plus, it's nice that the Service Generator automatically builds async methods for you :)

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect the easier alternative. It's really not a black/white decision, but the key is keeping your asynchronousity in ONE layer to help avoid memory leaks and unexpected results.

Comment: What about these so-called "Application Services" like IRegionManager? Would this be a good place to implement the asynchronicity? If I call an "Application Service" in a separate thread and it needs to store a state (maybe a cache), it will complain that you can only set data from the UI thread.

Comment: Hmm, never used the IRegionManager, so I can't speak to that.

Comment: My Question is if there is no clear way for waiting for a result, from an async function, without using a callback, don't this mean that this is a fault of C# self or Prism as it isn't able to handle async?